# PHP login "wall" with authorization

Tags: library, php, authentication, login

I'm developing a PHP tool, but my tool is missing the login functionality. Instead of developing that part myself, I wonder if there is a good library out there that solves this task?

My idea is to have this library as a login wall before entering my tool.

**My requirements**

- Authorization - Check if user is logged in or not
- Login form or some way to programmatically login a user from user and password
- Can be used with just PHP (and possibly MySQL). No Cake or Laravel.
- High security (not like a bank, but maybe like WordPress)

**Wishes**

- Cookie support, to remember the user longer than a PHP session
- That the library is trusted by many people
- I prefer to not have a big framework, but a small library
- Social media login features are not needed